# Can it be ROS master is dropping remote connections

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have RPi (Raspbian 9/kinetic) and a PC (bionic/melodic). They are connected directly via an Ethernet cable and dnsmasq. I would guess that there is no firewal, because (`pi$` is the command line on Pi, `pc$` is the command line on the pc)

```
pi$ netcat -l 11311
pc$ netcat pi 11311
```

works fine, and in the opposite direction

```
pc$ netcat -l 11311
pi$ netcat pi 11311
```

the two ends can talk one to another as well. Also, they say that there is no firewall by default in Raspbian9 and Ubuntu19, but I removed ufw just to be sure. Now when I run the master on pi, I can talk with it locally:

```
pi$ netcat localhost 11311
q
<head>
<title>Error response</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Error response</h1>
<p>Error code 400.
<p>Message: Bad request syntax ('q').
<p>Error code explanation: 400 = Bad request syntax or unsupported method.
</body>
```

But the same on the pc just exits:

```
pc$ netcat pi 11311
pc$
```

I know that it looks like a firewall, but why netcat can talk with itself via 11311 in both directions on the same machines?

Here is my .bashrc on pi:

```
  export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
  export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://$ROS_HOSTNAME:11311
  source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
  source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

and here on the pc:

```
  export ROS_IP=10.42.0.216
  export ROS_HOSTNAME=pi
  export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://$ROS_HOSTNAME:11311
  source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
  source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

ROS_IP is the IP of pi in /etc/hosts:

```
  127.0.0.1       localhost
  127.0.1.1       art
  10.42.0.216     pi
```

I just added it to be sure. This works fine as well:

```
pc$ ssh pi@pi
pi$ ssh art@rosmaster
```

iptables on both systems:

```
pi# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I wonder if ROS master drops remote connections for whatever purpose? If not, do you have any idea what a problem can it be? dnsmasq? An incompatibility between kinetic/bionic, whatever? But kinetic on Pi does not ask for anything, in particular it does not ask about the version of the other distribution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303383/can-it-be-ros-master-is-dropping-remote-connections/) by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2018-09-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2018-09-14**:
Did you try

```
export ROS_IP=10.42.0.216
export ROS_HOSTNAME=pi.local
```

**Comment by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) on 2018-09-14**:
I tried the same with pi instead of pi.local, as seen in .bashrc in the question; avahi sets pi as raspberrypi.local and  tried it as well

**Comment by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) on 2018-09-14**:
also, netcat, a low-level tool, sees nothing listening on both pi:11311 and raspberrypi.local:11311; it sees, however, the ports themselves as there is no "name or service not known" error; and it can talk fine if there is also netcat on the pi side instead of roscore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think rosmaster will drop remote connections if the `ROS_HOSTNAME` or `ROS_MASTER_URI` is set to localhost. On the pi, try setting `ROS_HOSTNAME=pi` .

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) on 2018-09-14**:
You are right ahendrix. Now it works.